# cordova device plugin UUID

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, device, uuid

until lately, the cordova device plugin delivered a 16byte string (as described in the documentation), e.g. "c2498955ecb5241b".

But suddenly, I am not getting this UUID anymore, but a browser identification string such as "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; GT-I9195 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"

I had to change the source from which the plugin is installed (I am using Adobe PhoneGap Build to create the app):

Has anybody an idea, what changed in this respect?

Comment: sorry. the installation source got stripped out:  **bold**plugin name= cordova-plugin-device  source= npm**bold**

Comment: Do you mean device.uuid from  cordova-plugin-device ?